# How to read the url fragment using Dart Shelf?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-shelf

I am trying to create a server using Dart Shelf, and on one path I want to read the data or params after the '#', i.e the fragment. But I am unable to do so, I have been trying the following:

```
app.get('/', (Request request) {
  print(request.requestedUri.fragment);
});
```

But this returns an empty string.

Edit:-
My path for the get request I am making is: `http://localhost:8000/#code=asdfd`